# How to make an object parameter from rest optional?

Tags: java, json, rest, resteasy

I'm using Resteasy, and on an specific resource, we can receive an Error object or not.

```
@POST
@Path("/product/{confirmationId}")
public void productConfirmation(@PathParam("confirmationId") String confirmationId,Error error);
```

How can I ignore this object when the caller doesn't send me a Error object?

Comment: I don't know Resteasy but you create a 2nd URL and create two separate overloaded method with one that accepts Error and one that does not. In the case when the user doesn't provide an Error object is the object null? If so you can do an if...else checking whether the value is null.

Comment: @wxkevin when i call a service and it returns an error object, how can i get this object from response?

Comment: Is this for the body of the POST? Have you already registered a Provider for your Error class? Can it return null if the body is empty or non-existent?

Comment: @PaulHicks yes, is for the body. I can return empty response if OK (200) or an 510 (Cannot Proccess Request) and an Error object in the body of response.